# DataGridView Cell Alignment Won't Work

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, styles, alignment

I have a DataGridView that I use in a C# Winforms project.  The grid does NOT autogenerate columns.  I have manually set the column names and properties.

This includes the DefaultCellStyle for the cells.  I want all cells that are of type DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn to be aligned centered.  I have manually set this alignment for each column of this type in the designer.  These changes do not show up when the datagridview is loaded.

As my next approach, I used the code below in the DataBindingComplete event (which also had no effect)

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvc in this.dgv_Automations.Columns)
{
    if(dgvc.CellType == typeof(DataGridViewCheckBoxCell))
        dgvc.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
}
```

When debugging, the above code already had the alignment set the center.  However, it still does not show up on the grid.

I **CAN** get it working if during the DataBindingComplete event I do something like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in this.dgv_Automations.Rows)
{
    dgvr.Cells["isErrors"].Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
}
```

However, I have many of these columns and it really doesn't make sense to do it this way.  EDIT: I have implemented it this way and with only about 10 rows there is very noticeable lag from setting this property on each cell.

My question is: what is the proper way of doing this?  Why does the designer DefaultCellStyle not work?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.defaultcellstyle.aspx) the `DefaultCellStyle` of a `DataGridViewColumn` is overridden by the styles specified through the `DataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle`, `DataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle`, `DataGridViewRow.DefaultCellStyle`, and `DataGridViewCell.Style` properties.
So it's possibile that one of these styles are set to a value incompatible with your required alignment (for example `DataGridViewContentAlignment.NotSet` or `DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopLeft`)

Answer (score 0):

An even more useful link for DefaultCellStyling and how the inheritance works.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0.aspx

Turned out I had set a DefaultRowStyle that was overriding DefaultCellStyle.  Make sure you check all the Styles!!

Answer (score 0):

WWITH .Net 4.8 ->
if you want that Alignment  will be "controlled" on a column basis with
DefaultCellStyle.Alignment for each column, edit your form x.Designer.cs file and comment your Alignment setting of the CellStyle of your Grid RowsDefaultCellStyle
Extract of (my) x.Designer.cs file ->
//dgv_CellStyle2.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
dgv_CellStyle2.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
dgv_CellStyle2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
this.Grid.RowsDefaultCellStyle = dgv_CellStyle2;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).