# Why doesn't cell text alignment doesn't work in DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, alignment

I want to make an input box and I have a DataGridView. But it does't work to align the text content of headers or cells.

**My code to create DataGridView at runtime:**

```
DataGridView CreateInputBox(int proc,int mac)
        {
            DataGridView databox = new DataGridView();
            for (int i = 0; i < mac; i++)
            {
                databox.Columns.Add("col" + i, "M" + i);
                databox.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < proc; i++)
            {
                databox.Rows.Add();
            }
            databox.AutoSize = true;
            databox.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
            return databox;
        }
```

**The result:**

[image]

So how can I do the alignment for the header and cells?

Comment: Check these: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17412270/3731444 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811641/datagridview-cell-alignment-wont-work

Comment: Thanks it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the answer is here: [Right align a column in datagridview doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404969/right-align-a-column-in-datagridview-doesnt-work/17412270#17412270)

And the problem is in the Sorting as when it’s enabled the DataGrid reserves some place for a sort glyph. So if you disable the sorting it should work as you expect:

```
this.DataGridView1.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

Adding this as an answer so everybody who will get here in the future will easily find the way to resolve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The code above is only to center the cells foreach column but not the header of each column.

Try to add this line in your "for" :

```
databox.Columns[i].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

Src: [Changing DataGridView Header Cells' Text Alignment And The Font Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967957/changing-datagridview-header-cells-text-alignment-and-the-font-size)

Comment: Sorry but this solution didn't work for me. Adding "NotSortable" did work.

Comment: Yes, I see. But you still missed the line for header cell :)